# How to Subtract day on date-time column - SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have two columns which have `YYYY MM DD MM SS` format and I want to subtract days between these two columns (DD)

```
201810031030 YYYY MM DD MM SS - 201810051030 YYYY MM DD MM SS  = 3(03-05)
```

I have a SQL function which converts MM Month to string(i.e January).

Any suggestion highly appreciated

Below is the SQL and the error I get:

```
DATEDIFF(DAY, CAST(IST COLUMN) AS DATETIME), CAST (2ND COLUMN) AS DATETIME))
```

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Currently the datatype is `VARCHAR` (201810031030) and I would like to cast it on the fly

Comment: If you have date time data, you really should be storing it using the proper datatype -- DATE, TIME, DATETIME, etc. Do so, and all your date time manipulations problems become much, much simpler to resolve.

Comment: Are they really space separated?

Comment: @Salman A totally agree I must have overlooked at the datatype.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the DateDiff function:

```
datediff(day,column1,column2)
```

Answer (score 0):

The optimal solution would be to change your database structure using the correct data type (`datetime`).

If this is not possible you can use `stuff` to build a standard `datetime` format and do a `cast` to `datetime`. Then you can use `datediff` to calculate difference in days:

```
declare @tmp table (date_1 varchar(50), date_2 varchar(50))

insert into @tmp values ('201810031030','201810051030')

select 
     cast(stuff(stuff(date_1, 11,0,':') + ':00', 9,0,' ') as datetime) as date_1
    ,cast(stuff(stuff(date_2, 11,0,':') + ':00', 9,0,' ') as datetime) as date_2

    ,DATEDIFF(
        day,
        cast(stuff(stuff(date_1, 11,0,':') + ':00', 9,0,' ') as datetime),
        cast(stuff(stuff(date_2, 11,0,':') + ':00', 9,0,' ') as datetime)
    ) + 1 as diff
from @tmp
```

Result:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You would need to basically do something like this to keep it pretty standard and simple. This is basically bad practice from a database point of view but it is possible that there is a legitimate need for the data in that format so, I am not one to judge. This should get you what you are looking for with each execution:

```
DECLARE @oddDTFormat1 AS CHAR(12);
DECLARE @oddDTFormat2 AS CHAR(12);
DECLARE @newDTFormat1 AS DATETIME;
DECLARE @newDTFormat2 AS DATETIME;

SET @oddDTFormat1 = '201809010030';
SET @oddDTFormat2 = '201809031037';


SET @newDTFormat1 = CONVERT(DATETIME, LEFT(@oddDTFormat1, 8), 112) + CONVERT(DATETIME, CONCAT(SUBSTRING(@oddDTFormat1, 9, 2), ':', SUBSTRING(@oddDTFormat1, 11, 2)), 114);

SET @newDTFormat2 = CONVERT(DATETIME, LEFT(@oddDTFormat2, 8), 112) + CONVERT(DATETIME, CONCAT(SUBSTRING(@oddDTFormat2, 9, 2), ':', SUBSTRING(@oddDTFormat2, 11, 2)), 114);

SELECT DATEDIFF(DAY, @newDTFormat1, @newDTFormat2);
```

Thanks,
Dave Betournay
PV9685

Comment: Please forgive me the code formatting this machine is not set up for SQL so I am working in a browser and validating with web tools. ;)

Comment: Also, if you care about performance, reliability, and accuracy of this code and plan to perform operations on your Date/Time data for years to come you would want to do something like create a new table and use the code I supplied to create a table of DATETIME data. To support legacy code use something like a view to turn the DATETIME into the proprietary format you are currently using. If this is part of a decently sized business it would be wise to do this before the database becomes even more complex, or after years when employees change and confusion sets in.